# Verify the length of a variable

Tags: bash, shell, string

I've to verify the length of variable read (my script limit to five the characters inserted), I think about something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read string
check=${#string}
echo $check
if [ $check -ge 5 ]; then echo "error" ; exit
else echo "done"
fi
```

is there a more "elegant" solution?

Comment: Your script works correctly in standard POSIX `/bin/sh`. You should consider changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh` so that it will be more portable and run in environments where bash isn't available. Plus, `/bin/sh` might be a more lightweight shell like dash which isn't burdened with features meant for interactive use.

Comment: @Celada, true though in this case, `dash`'s `${#string}` would give you the length in number of bytes instead of characters.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

More elegant? No

Shorter? Yes :)

```
#!/bin/bash
read string
if [ ${#string} -ge 5 ]; then echo "error" ; exit
else echo "done"
fi
```

And if you have no problem on trading more elegance in favor of being shorter, you can have a script with 2 lines less:

```
#!/bin/bash
read string
[ ${#string} -ge 5 ] && echo "error" || echo "done"
```

You could use double brackets if you think it is safer. [Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/2231796).

Answer (score 4):

A Bourne-compatible alternative (`${#string}` is POSIX but not Bourne (not that you're likely to ever come across a Bourne shell these days)):

```
case $string in
  ?????*) echo >&2 Too long; exit 1;;
       *) echo OK
esac
```

Note that for both `${#string}` and `????`, whether it will be the number of bytes or characters will depend on the shell. Generally (and it's required by POSIX), it is the number of characters. But for some shells like `dash` that are  not multi-byte aware, it will be bytes instead.

With `mksh`, you need `set -o utf8-mode` (in UTF-8 locales) for it to understand multi-byte characters:

```
$ string=€€€ bash -c 'echo "${#string}"'
3
$ string=€€€ dash -c 'echo "${#string}"'
9
$ string=€€€ mksh -c 'echo "${#string}"'
9
$ string=€€€ mksh -o utf8-mode -c 'echo "${#string}"'
3
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
```

Comment: off topic, but is `echo Too long` different under the hood from `echo 'Too long'`

Comment: And, if you will just print when it's "too long", i can compact even more on my `if` option :)

Comment: @StevenPenny, `echo Too long` passes two arguments (`Too` and `long`) to `echo` which `echo` outputs separated by a space (and followed by a newline), while in `echo 'Too long'`, we pass one `Too long` argument to `echo` which it displays following by a newline. So it's functionnaly equivalent.