# Display result of a command right aligned in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a script that goes through many different checks and I use the `success`, `failure` functions defined in `/etc/init.d/functions` to clearly show the action result on the terminal.

That works great, except in some cases where I print a bit more text, I then get the result box displayed *over my text*:

`/usr/share/app/lib/lib_mylib.so     lib[  OK  ]o matches as expected`

Where I'd like it to be displayed:

`/usr/share/app/lib/lib_mylib.so     lib_mylib.so matches as expected      [  OK  ]`

Looking around I saw that `/etc/init.d/functions` is using a variable `RES_COL` to position where to print the result field. If `/etc/sysconfig/init` exists then `RES_COL` is taken from there, set by default to 60 chars.

I've tried `export RES_COL=100` after sourcing `/etc/init.d/functions` to no avail.
Furthermore I'd like the result field to be **right-aligned** with the terminal window and not having to hard-code any value for that. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `tput` command can be used to control the cursor, assuming you have your `TERM` variable set correctly. In combination with the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables, you can position the cursor wherever you want.

The syntax is:

```
tput cup line column
```

For example:

```
tput cup $((LINES-2)) $((COLUMNS-4));echo "[OK]"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using that file, one might assume this is part of the boot-up process and that the `TERM` environment has not been set (making the use of [**`tput`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) moot).  It uses hard-coded escape sequences for that purpose.

Also, setting `RES_COL` won't do much for your script unless it uses the value.  That's only used (Fedora) in that file.

You could add your own function, passing it the string to be printed, and check the length to compare against `$RES_COL`, and if it is longer, simply print that (to finish the line) and then on the next line use the **`$MOVE_TO_COL`** string to move to the response column before printing the response in `echo_success` or `echo_failure`.

For instance, you may be calling `action`:

```
action() {
    local STRING rc

    STRING=$1
    echo -n "$STRING "
    shift
    "$@" && success $"$STRING" || failure $"$STRING"
    rc=$?
    echo
    return $rc
}
```

You could redirect the output from the command to capture the output.  That interferes with the `rc=$?` line, but you can get that from bash's `$PIPESTATUS` variable:

```
    local RESULT
    RESULT=$("$@" 2>&1)
    rc=$PIPESTATUS
    echo -n "$RESULT"
    [ ${#RESULT} -ge $RES_COL ] && echo
    [ $rc = 0 ] success $"$STRING" || failure $"$STRING"
```

Further reading:

- [Pipe output and capture exit status in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status-in-bash)
- [Verify the length of a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145150/verify-the-length-of-a-variable)