# Length of a variable

Tags: linux, variable

I imported latitudes and longitudes from text files. These two textfiles contain a few thousand of numbers. I read them into variables, now I want to know just how many numbers are in these files. I used this question: [Verify the length of a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145150/verify-the-length-of-a-variable) but for some reason the output I get is `length of Lat is 1`.

```
#!/bin/sh

mapfile Latitude < final_ADCP_Saved.matLatitude.txt
mapfile Longitude < final_ADCP_Saved.matLongitude.txt


echo "length of Lat is ${#Latitude[@]}"
echo "length of Lon is ${#Longitude[@]}"
```

If I say `echo "$Longitude` the output is

```
3.4269394e+00   3.4240913e+00   3.4212670e+00   3.4184430e+00   3.4156012e+00   3.4126834e+00   3.4097271e+00   3.4069235e+00   3.4041572e+00   3.4010903e+00   3.3982218e+00   3.3953517e+00   3.3925018e+00   3.3897342e+00   3.3868243e+00   3.3839234e+00   3.3810560e+00
```

How do I determine the length of these variables?

Comment: please post an example of your original files.

Comment: I suspect that the text files don't have newlines between the values, so `mapfile` reads the entire file into one array element. You may need to pass `-d` to specify the delimiter.

Comment: There's no `mapfile` in the standard sh syntax. If you're using bash-specific features, you should use a `#! /path/to/bash -` shebang

Comment: `echo "$Longitude"` only outputs the element of indice zero in the array in bash. To display all elements, one per line, you'd need `printf '%s\n' "${Longitude[@]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have newlines between the values. Hence you need to specifiy the delimiter via `-d`:

```
mapfile -d ' ' Latitude < final_ADCP_Saved.matLatitude.txt
mapfile -d ' ' Longitude < final_ADCP_Saved.matLongitude.txt
```

This should now correctly place each latitude/longitude into its own array element.

EDIT:
The `-d` option seems to be a modern bashism. Another way of fixing this would seem to be use `tr` to convert the spaces into newlines (and use `-s` to squeeze duplicates out):

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLatitude.txt | mapfile Latitude
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as the pipeline causes `mapfile` to be run in a subshell and hence the variable isn't available in the main shell.

Workaround is to first change the standard input of the shell to a process substitution, and then run `mapfile`:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLatitude.txt)
mapfile Latitude
exec < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLongitude.txt)
mapfile Longitude

echo "length of Lat is ${#Latitude[@]}"
echo "length of Lon is ${#Longitude[@]}"
```

Note that I changed the first line to `#!/bin/bash` as this will only work in bash.

EDIT2

Now I think about it, the `exec` part doesn't need to be done separately:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile Latitude < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLatitude.txt)
mapfile Longitude < <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < final_ADCP_Saved.matLongitude.txt)

echo "length of Lat is ${#Latitude[@]}"
echo "length of Lon is ${#Longitude[@]}"
```

Comment: I get the error that -d is not an option `./geknoei.sh: line 3: mapfile: -d: invalid option
mapfile: usage: mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
length of Lat is 0
`